# Ubuntu 19.04 + Nvidia MX150

Tags: nvidia, performance, 19.04, bumblebee

I can't find any related info about this, maybe because of how new 19.04 is?

I don't see the proprietary drivers in the additional software window...
I only see the open source drivers which don't perform very well...

I've tried all kinds of things to improve performance here, install the .run file from the nvidia site, use bumblebee (never got it to work either because the nvidia module is not loaded or something like this).

Also if I install the .run file from the website, glxgears shows me thousands of fps, but the games don't work and Ubuntu in general is really laggy...

Any idea what else could I try?
Oh, I also disabled the secure boot.

As requested, the output of `ubuntu-drivers devices`

```
➜  ~ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D10sv00001043sd0000163Ebc03sc02i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108M [GeForce MX150]
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, make sure that **proprietary drivers** and **restricted software** repositories are enabled. You need to have these enabled in order for proprietary drivers to show up under additional drivers tab. To do this, please run in the terminal:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Then, make sure to enable the repositories by selecting the check marks like in the image below and clicking on **Close** when done:

[image]

Then, please click on **Reload** like in the image below:

[image]

After that, please wait for the repositories to reload before you proceed to installing your GPU's drivers as usual.

Based on the output you posted of `ubuntu-drivers devices`:

The recommended proprietary NVIDIA driver for your system is `nvidia-driver-430`. You can install it like so:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
```

You will need to reboot after that for the changes to take effect.

You can as well experiment with the other available proprietary NVIDIA drivers `nvidia-driver-410`, `nvidia-driver-390`, and `nvidia-driver-415`. like so:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-VERSION_NUMBER
```

Replace VERSION_NUMBER with the version number you wand like 410, 390, or 415

**Please be careful** if you decide to install other versions that are not recommended for your system. Your desktop GUI might not work properly.

---

After installation and reboot you might need to select NVIDIA GPU and disable INTEL GPU if you have dual GPU. You can do this by running the following in the terminal:

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

Then select the NVIDIA GPU like in the image below ( you might get a slightly different screen with more options ) but what you need to change is **prime**:

[image]

After that, please reboot your system.

---

Regarding the error message you get:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA
>   driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
>   running.

It appears that you have attempted to install, purge and reinstall different NVIDIA drivers too many times but not all of the attempts were successful, so your system ended up with mixed bits and pieces of every driver.

To fix this, you will need to purge every bit of NVIDIA software on your system, by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

After that, please run the following command to install a clean copy of the NVIDIA drivers by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Then, please reboot your system after that for the new driver to be loaded.

Comment: Hi there @Raffa thx for your suggestions, for some reason this doesn't work for me, i already had the propietary drivers checkbox marked (i marked it when installing ubuntu) But i dont see any reload message or new drivers in the list :/

Comment: @Yorutamashi Please run in the terminal `ubuntu-drivers devices` and add the output to your question by editing it.

Comment: i added the data, thx!

Comment: @Yorutamashi Kindly, see the updated answer. If you need help, please let me know. Best of luck

Comment: so i thought these weren't propietary because it says third party open source, also i tried with the 430 one and the performance is really bad... i get only 50-70 fps with glxgears, i ve seen other people get over 2000fps with the same graphics card. And obviously i've tried other games on windows in this laptop and it works much better there, ideas on how to improve performance?

Comment: @Yorutamashi These are proprietary NVIDIA drivers. You might need to run `nvidia-settings` and enable the NVIDIA GPU for it to be used correctly. You can do this from the GUI.

Comment: @Yorutamashi Kindly, see the updated answer.

Comment: @Rafall thx for all the help :) I've tried this too i already had NVIDIA selected in this window but the performance is still suboptimal

Comment: @Yorutamashi You are most welcome. As far as I can imagine, your card is configured properly. Nothing more can be done except to try and change some of the setting in NVIDIA administration panel to see if you can raise the performance. Or perhaps experiment with the other drivers versions. Have a nice day

Comment: Thx for all the help, still there are some weird things like when i do `nvidia-msi` i get the message `NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.` 
Which i guess is not cool.
Also i've seen online that if manage to enable bumblebee i can improve the performance significantly. But when i tried to install it i always get stuff like "nvidia module not found"

Comment: @Yorutamashi Kindly see the updated answer.

Comment: hi there again and once more thanks for your time and help, i've tried all you mentioned to no avail :(
I've just reinstalled ubuntu 19.04 and tried from scratch but im stuck again at basically teh same point, i created another question for this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1168029/ubuntu-19-04-cant-enable-or-select-nvidia-card-as-default
If you have time please check that other post and see what you think.
Thanks!

Comment: @Yorutamashi Hi again. I will sure try my best. Please provide the brand and the model number of your machine so I search for it to know its configuration.

Comment: it's an ASUS VivoBook s15, apparently there some issue with the kernel in ubuntu and the buggy hardware for the optimus thingy. So i'll give a try to Manjaro, which has newer kernels. If it is still doesn't work i guess i'll bounce back to Windows :(

Comment: @Yorutamashi Please run `sudo lshw -c display` and then run `prime-select query` and add the output of both to your question. Then please run `sudo prime-select nvidia` and add the output if there is any. Then please run `prime-select query` again and add the output if different from the first time.