# Ubuntu 19.04 - Can't enable or select Nvidia card as default

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 19.04, intel, nomodeset

I've been trying for weeks now to use my Laptop with an MX150 card to run some games in Ubuntu.
But for some reason linux doesn't want to let me use it!

Things I've tried:

- I've installed the latest drivers (430)
- done `prime-select nvidia`, query shows `nvidia` as selected too.
- I've also disabled secure boot from the BIOS.
- I've added `nomodeset` to the grub config, but this boots to a blinking cursos and black screen until i remove that.
- I just tried installing bumblebee to run stuff, i get this message:
  `[ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)`

If i have nvidia Drivers installed, for some reason I'm forced to login selecting Wayland from the user select screen otherwise it bounces back to the user list.

And I still see in Settings > Details that the system is still using the intel Card. Even thought the nvidia drivers are suggested in the Software app and i have installed the 430 ones.

Also if i run tools like glxgears or glmark2 it uses the intel card instead of the Nvidia card to do the tests :/

I don't know what else to try to use my graphics card... it seems at this point i will have to go back to Winbugs :(

Any other ideas what to do?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Have you tried a non-wayland option while logging in? See this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1148182/855322

Comment: hi there @FedonKadifeli, thanks for replying, but yeah like i mentioned in the post:
`When i can see the login screen, for some reason I'm forced to login selecting Wayland from the user select screen otherwise it bounces back to the user list.
`

Comment: I've noticed using a nvidia-debug tool, that the nvidia card is not loading as hardware, i even tried updating the laptop's BIOS and still linux won't pick it up... it's a shame i would have loved to be able to use linux and game :(
I guess i'll just go back to windows then