# How to properly install drivers for Nvidia GeForce MX150 and enable it instead of Intel UHD graphics?

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I have Asus Vivobook with following specifications

1. Intel 8250U
2. NVIDIA GeForce MX150
3. 8GB memory
4. Ubuntu 18.04

**system specification:**

[image: system specification]

I'm trying to install drivers for NVIDIA GeForce MX150 and enable it.

The following are the drivers listed by `ubuntu-drivers devices`

1. *driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - third-party free
2. *driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
3. *driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
4. *driver   : nvidia-driver-440 - third-party free recommended

**drivers listed by Ubuntu:**

[image: drivers listed by Ubuntu]

I have tried installing all the four drivers (390, 415, 410 & 440), but none of them worked. 
It still shows that Intel graphics is being used (in Settings -> About).

**Intel graphics being used:**

[image: Intel graphics being used]

Prime Select status also shows that NVIDIA is selected.

**prime-select status:**

[image: prime-select status]

I would like to mention here that `lspci | grep -i vga` lists only Intel UHD Graphics as **VGA compatible controller**. But `lspci -nn | grep '\[0302\]'` lists NVIDIA GeForce MX150 as a **3D controller**.

Comment: Please follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1166705/968501)